# plotting the total monthly amount of rain from a daily data file with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've got a data file with daily values for the amount of rain in the 4th column, for each day of the year.
I'd like to plot a bar graph with each month in the x-axis, and the total monthly amount of rain in the y-axis: that is, to plot "January" (with %B or %b format) vs the sum of the 31 first values of the 4th column. Then to plot "February" vs the sum of the next 28 values of the 4th column, and so on. Do you know how to do that with gnuplot ? Besides, is it possible to write the numerical value of the monthly amounts of rain, on top of each bar ?

Comment: What is your exact data  format? What have you tried so far? Please show your code. On StackOverflow it is common sense that you show your own research effort. SO is not a coding service, like "I have no clue (or I am too lazy to search), please show me how to do this and that." Show your non-working coding and graph attempt and we will make suggestions how to fix it. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: any feedback would be appreciated. Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine and understand that for a gnuplot beginner it will not be easy to find and combine the necessary commands to realize your task. If you do a search you will most probably not find exactly your case, but there should be very similar questions and examples around. The key search would be "creating a histogram".

Check `help smooth frequency`, `help strftime`, `help strptime`, `help datablocks`, `help table`, basically for every command or keyword there should be a help entry.

The following example is one way to achieve what you are asking for. It is basically binning data, like creating a histogram. Here, your bins will be the months in the following numerical format, e.g. `202109`, `202110`, `202111`, `202112`, `202201`, etc.

In the example below, some random test data (mm  of rain per day) will be created in order to illustrate the result with a graph.
Example data in `$Data`:

```
2021-12-01 66
2021-12-02 0
2021-12-03 0
2021-12-04 17
2021-12-05 52
```

Plot your data into a datablock `$Monthly` using the option `smooth frequency`. It will sum up all values per month.
The result in `$Monthly` will be something like this:

```
 202107  368
 202108  622
 202109  557
 202110  361
 202111  628
```

I hope you can adapt the code to your data and needs.

**Edit:** the previous version of the code used the plotting style `with boxes` for the monthly plot. However, this style is centering the box at the beginning of the month, which is undesired here (especially when plotting together with the daily rain). The modified code is using the plotting style `with boxxyerror` which plots the boxes from the beginning of the month to the beginning of the next month. Check `help boxes` and `help boxxyerror`.

**Code:**

```
### sum up monthly rainfall
reset session
TimeFmtInput = "%Y-%m-%d"

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    StartDate = strptime(TimeFmtInput,"2021-04-01")
    do for [i=0:280] {
        RainMM = int(rand(0)+0.3) * rand(0)*100
        print sprintf("%s %.0f",strftime(TimeFmtInput,StartDate+3600*24*i),RainMM)
    }
set print

set table $Monthly
    plot $Data u (tm_year(timecolumn(1,TimeFmtInput))*100+tm_mon(timecolumn(1,TimeFmtInput))+1):2 smooth freq
unset table

set style fill solid 0.3
set format x "%Y\n%b" timedate
set key out top center
set grid x,y
set xtics out

NextMonth(t) = strptime("%Y%m",sprintf("%04d%02d",tm_year(t),tm_mon(t)+2))
NextDay(t)   = t + 24*3600

set multiplot layout 2,1
    plot $Data u (t0=timecolumn(1,TimeFmtInput)):2:(t0):(NextDay(t0)):(0):2 w boxxy lc "blue" title "Daily rain / mm"

    set xrange[GPVAL_X_MIN:GPVAL_X_MAX]   # take the same xrange as the previous plot
    plot $Monthly u (t0=timecolumn(1,"%Y%m")):2:(t0):(NextMonth(t0)):(0):2 w boxxy lc "blue" title "Monthly rain / mm"
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]